# How are integer operations implemented in Python?

Tags: python

This might be a very broad question. I wanted to create a way to represent strings that would support O(1) append, O(1) append to the left, and O(1) comparison while maintaining O(N) slicing and O(1) indexing. My idea is that I would store unicode characters as their unicode number, and use mathematical operations to add and delete characters from either end. I called it NumString:

```
class Numstring:
    def __init__(self, init_str=""):
        self.num = 0
        self.length = 0

        for char in init_str:
            self.append(char)

    def toString(self, curr=None):
        if curr is None:
            curr = self.num

        retlst = []

        while curr:
            char = chr(curr % 10000)
            retlst.append(char)
            curr = curr // 10000

        return "".join(retlst)

    def appendleft(self, char):
        assert len(char) == 1
        self.num *= 10000
        self.num += ord(char)
        self.length += 1

    def append(self, char):
        self.num += ord(char)*(10000**self.length)
        self.length += 1    

    def pop(self):
        # self.num = self.num % (10000**self.length-1)
        self.num = self.num % 10000**(self.length-1)
        self.length -= 1

    def popleft(self):
        self.num = self.num // 10000
        self.length -= 1

    def compare(self, numstring2):
        return self.num == numstring2.num

    def size(self):
        return self.length

    def get(self, start, end=None):
        if start >= self.length:
            raise IndexError("index out of bounds")
        if end and end > self.length + 1:
            raise IndexError("index out of bounds")

        if end is not None:
            if start == end:
                return ""

            curr = self.num

            curr = curr // (10000 ** start)

            curr = curr % 10000**(end)

            return self.toString(curr)
        else:
            curr = self.num

            curr = curr // (10000 ** start)

            char = chr(curr % 10000)
            return char
```

Here is the profiling code:

```
import string
import time
import random
from NumString import Numstring
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
if __name__ == '__main__':
    

    numstring_times = []
    regstring_times = []

    numstring = Numstring("abc")
    regstring = "abc"

    for i in range(0, 10000):
        char_to_add = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        
        start_time = time.time()
        numstring.append(char_to_add)
        end_time = time.time()

        numstring_times.append(end_time-start_time)

        start_time = time.time()
        regstring += char_to_add
        end_time = time.time()

        regstring_times.append(end_time-start_time)

    plt.plot(numstring_times, label="Numstring")
    plt.plot(regstring_times, label="Regular strings")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

It works the way I want it to, but when I tested the time it takes to append to the string and my Numstring class performed way worse. I understood that there would be overhead, but I didn't expect the overall trend to be way worse than concatenating strings in python.

[image: Time it takes to append a character to]

Curiously, comparison times are actually better for Numstrings than regular strings:

[image: Comparison times for Numstrings vs Regular strings]

I've realized I don't really understand how integer operations in Python are implemented and what the limitations of infinite integer precision are. Could somebody help me understand what I'm missing?

Comment: provide the profiling code...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int`s are essentially represented as strings of digits (in a higher base than 10), and most operations on them, including addition and multiplication, take time proportional to the number of digits they contain or worse. Because the base you’re using (10000) doesn’t match the base `int`s use, operations like multiplying or dividing by the base become a complex operation instead of a simple copying of bytes of memory. So it’s pretty much a less efficient reimplementation of the operations strings already do (which is what you found by benchmarking) and it doesn’t support all of Unicode (which goes up to 0x10FFFF, not 10000).

Hint for a data structure that actually has the properties you’re looking for, though: a deque based on a circular buffer.

Comment: I thought of using a deque, but I also wanted O(1) comparison. In my understanding, to compare two strings you have to go through all the characters and see if they're equal. I wanted to use numbers because I thought it was an O(1) operation to compare. I guess to a computer, there's no way to actually get O(1) comparison, since you'll always need to check the bytes

Comment: @AlexPeniz: It isn’t an O(1) operation to compare arbitrary-size ints. Like the rest of the operations, it’s O(digits). Algorithms often work with integers of bounded size (and integers in other languages are often bounded, even), whose operations can be considered O(1) because of that.

Comment: got it, that makes a lot of sense. Sad, I spent a fair bit of time on this haha

Comment: @AlexPeniz: You can get probabilistic O(1) comparison, though, by storing a hash alongside the deque and updating them in sync. The probability of failure can even be negligible, through use of a cryptographic hash (warning: asymptotically fast, but with a big constant factor). It kind of depends on what you’re using it for.

Comment: @AlexPeniz that's why the first rule of optimization is to profile.  Your intuition will often lead you astray.

Comment: @Ry- As a follow up question, I did a little comparison of regular strings and numstrings for the comparison operation, and it seems that numstrings have better comparison times than regular strings. I posted a picture in the original. Could you shed some light on how strings vs integers are compared?

Comment: @Ry- deque only has two out of the five properties. It does *not* have O(1) comparison, does *not* have O(N) slicing (where N is the slice length, as in string slicing) and does *not* have O(1) indexing.

Comment: @superbrain: Comparison has already been covered, but you’re right about indexing, and I’m very surprised.

Comment: @AlexPeniz: Correction: not `collections.deque`, but a deque based on a circular buffer, has the properties you’re looking for.

Comment: @Ry- Yes, I've seen the comments about comparison, but the answer still says that deque has that.